# How to test a program against a particular device without having the device?

Tags: testing, operating-system, virtual-machine, driver

I was wondering if there is any solution to test a hardware-dependent software against a particular device.

For example consider a program which depends on Bluetooth or printer, using it through the OS APIs. How does developers deal with a situation when a users report that it does not work properly on a particular laptop model, if there is not enough debugging information available.

As another example, how can we know what paper sizes a specific printer supports without buying one and running a program on it to enumerate supported sizes.

Is there any way to simulate that device/driver or any service that provide the ability to test against that device?

Comment: Have the user send you the laptop.  Alternatively, start loading your own laptop, debugging tools, test equipment, cables etc. into a case and start making travel plans:)

Comment: @MartinJames If it's a mass market low price or free software, user does not care/want to get involved at all.

Comment: Down voter may want to explain why? After contributing in stackoverflow for a few years, I just asked a very few questions, most of the times no answers or pathetic down votes is what I've got.

Answer (score 4):

Some things can be "emulated" others will force you to have at least the basic hardware so that later you could run a set of tests besides trying to code following standards, RFC's, etc. For example in the case of printers: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7472 and [cups-pdf](https://www.cups-pdf.de), could help, but that will cover just the basics.

In some cases, the hardware is bought and co-located within a rack in a datacenter where later the developers access to it remotely by using a [KVM over IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) also known as ("spider").

If a specific feature/bug needs to be tested in a specific system, there are companies that could lease the hardware (Mac/PC/phones/tablets/etc) saving cost with this.

Besides shipping a "debug/report" tool could help in many cases to better diagnose the running system or catch/report issues if any.

For testing mobile devices you could use for example [AWS Device Farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/)

Comment: "there are companies that could lease the hardware" what companies? I found [one](https://appkitbox.com/en/testkit/) for mobile, but nothing for PCs, laptops or other hardware.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz search for example "rent online mac" there are multiple providers, I updated the answer with another link for mobile devices, hope it can help

Comment: I'm interested in PC laptops not Macs. There are only a few model of Macs while there are many PC laptop models, that's where the problem comes from. Couldn't find any by googling, most the results are about renting the device physically not remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the device is connected via USB, and, exists somewhere in your sphere of systems, you could take a look at this project (http://usbip.sourceforge.net) - lets you talk to the actual device over IP on another server, using USB as the DPI (device programming interface).

A second way to go would be to write an emulator as a virtual driver - probably more expensive than just buying the device, but we did that once when we were co-developing the hardware and the software, and the hardware didn't actually exist in working form.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a quite general question, you can get better answer for a class of devices.

My opinion is that it's possible, it will need some more or less extensive work depending on the device class, device, and function you want to probe. A certain class of devices have shared functions, and have specific functions. I understand that you want to get generic informations, the shared ones.

First thing to keep in mind is that a driver is an interface between the OS (eg., kernel) and the hardware. So there is a shared *interface*. Drivers can be extremely complex (eg. graphic drivers), and might have their own GUI and inner logic, and I think that if you stay out of this part, you can workout a  program that will give you that answers you want to get of a class of devices.

I think the most generic/general way is to achieve *how to get information about a device* this is to get the drivers, extract the symbols from the `dll` (`dumpbin.exe /exports`) or `so` file and findout which answers you can get if you request for example which format a printer can use. To get the possible answers would require to get into the driver's logic, eg with [IDA pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/).

For that task, you might need to use also dependencies.

On FreeBSD, we can build a *freebsd driver* from the windows binaries of the driver ([Setting Up Network Interface Cards](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/config-network-setup.html)). There is a translation from `FreeBSD calls` to `Windows calls`. Reading sources might help you see how it was done.

In the end, you can indeed go to hardware farms (as nbari mentionned the AWS mobile farms), or just ask a vendor tables about their hardware, or a driver test API that simulate the hardware so you can query directly the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible there are emulators out there?

If yes, use these, if no, use a similar emulator, first look for one by the same manufacturer and then any printer emulator, if there are none, the requirement is untestable unless the customer can be convinced that they need to buy the specific hardware they will use in Live. Sometimes you have to be the bearer of bad news but they are forcing your hand in a way that cannot be put at your door.

The latter is the course of action that carries least risk. If you are using any of the other suggestions you must tell your customer that the risk increases the further away from the hardware your tests will run. They then have to make the decision which course of action that has to be taken and, as a result, they must underwrite the risk.

Out of interest, if you are using the printer in live, can you not schedule a loan of one for the duration of your tests?

Unless I have misunderstood the question, this is the way I would go.